# `UserAnnotation()` function doesn't work with new SwiftUI Map API from `_MapKit_SwiftUI` in Xcode15

Tags: ios, swiftui, location, mapkit, xcode15

From apple documentation [Meet MapKit for SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10043) video I have tried to follow the video tutorial and use `UserAnnotation()` function in order to get the user location in simulator as like the video. But it's not working.

**BeantownButtons.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

@available(iOS 17.0, *)
struct BeantownButtons: View {
    @Binding var searchResults: [MKMapItem]
    @Binding var position: MapCameraPosition
    
    var visibleRegion: MKCoordinateRegion?
    func search(for query: String) {
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = query
        request.resultTypes = .pointOfInterest
        request.region = visibleRegion ?? MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: .parking,
            span: MKCoordinateSpan (latitudeDelta: 0.0125, longitudeDelta: 0.0125))
        Task {
            let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
            let response = try? await search.start()
            searchResults = response?.mapItems ?? []
            print("Search Results: \(searchResults)")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            Button {
                search(for: "playground")
            } label: {
                Label("Playgrounds", systemImage: "figure.and.child.holdinghands")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            
            Button {
                search(for: "beach")
            } label: {
                Label("Beaches", systemImage: "beach.umbrella")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            
            Button {
                position = .region(.boston)
            } label: {
                Label("Boston", systemImage: "building.2")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            
            Button {
                position = .region(.northShore)
            } label: {
                Label("North Shore", systemImage: "water.waves")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
    }
}

#Preview {
    if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
        BeantownButtons(searchResults: .constant([]), position: .constant(.automatic))
    } else {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

**ItemInfoView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import _MapKit_SwiftUI

@available(iOS 17.0, *)
struct ItemInfoView: View {
    
    // ItemInfoView.swift - Fetch a Look Around scene
    @State  var lookAroundScene: MKLookAroundScene?
    @State  var route: MKRoute?
    @State  var selectedResult: MKMapItem

    func getLookAroundScene () {
        lookAroundScene = nil
        Task {
            let request = MKLookAroundSceneRequest(mapItem: selectedResult)
            lookAroundScene = try? await request.scene
        }
    }
    
    // ItemInfoView.swift - Format travel time for display
         var travelTime: String? {
            guard let route else { return nil }
            let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
            formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
            formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
            return formatter.string(from: route.expectedTravelTime)
        }

    var body: some View {
        LookAroundPreview(initialScene: lookAroundScene)
            .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                HStack {
                    Text ("\(selectedResult.name ?? "")")
                    if let travelTime {
                        Text(travelTime)
                    }
                }
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .padding (10)
            }
            .onAppear {
                getLookAroundScene()
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedResult) {
                getLookAroundScene()
            }
    }
}
#Preview {
    if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
        ItemInfoView(selectedResult: MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: .daraz)))
    } else {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

**CustomMapViewLookAround.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import _MapKit_SwiftUI

@available(iOS 17.0, *)
struct CustomMapViewLookAround: View {
    @State private var position: MapCameraPosition = .automatic
    @State private var visibleRegion: MKCoordinateRegion?
    @State  var route: MKRoute?
    @State var searchResults: [MKMapItem] = []
    @State private var selectedResult: MKMapItem?
    
    func getDirections() {
        print("results count: \(searchResults.count)")
        route = nil
        guard let selectedResult else { return }
        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: .parking))
        request.destination = selectedResult
        Task {
            let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
            let response = try? await directions.calculate()
            route = response?.routes.first
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(position: $position, selection: $selectedResult) {
            Annotation("Parking", coordinate: .parking) {
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .fill(.background)
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .stroke(.secondary, lineWidth: 5)
                    Image(systemName: "car")
                        .padding(5)
                }
            }
            .annotationTitles(.hidden)
            
            
            ForEach(searchResults, id: \.self) { result in
                Marker(item: result)
                //                    .tag(1)
            }
            .annotationTitles(.hidden)
            
            if let route {
                MapPolyline(route)
                    .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 5)
            }
            
            UserAnnotation()
            
        }
        .mapStyle(.standard)
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    if let selectedResult {
                        ItemInfoView(route: route, selectedResult: selectedResult)
                            .frame(height: 128)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle (cornerRadius: 10))
                            .padding([.top, .horizontal])
                    }
                    BeantownButtons(searchResults: $searchResults, position: $position, visibleRegion: visibleRegion)
                        .padding(.top)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(.thinMaterial)
        }
        .onChange(of: searchResults) {
            position = .automatic
        }
        .onMapCameraChange { context in
            visibleRegion = context.region
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedResult) {
            getDirections()
        }
        .mapControls {
            MapUserLocationButton()
            MapCompass()
            MapScaleView()
        }
        .onAppear {
            let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
        CustomMapViewLookAround()
    } else {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
CLLocationManager(<CLLocationManager: 0x600000010b20>) for <MKCoreLocationProvider: 0x600003000c60> did fail with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
```

Whenever I click the location button [image: Location Button]. It buffers forever. I have also add the location access privacy in info.plist. Moreover, set the simulator location like this [image: Set Simulator Location]

```
Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
```

[image: Current App View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found you still need to use the appropriate privacy keys in your Info.plist, and request location authorisation from `CLLocationManager` before the `UserAnnotation()` will display.

Comment: Added `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` to the info.plist which I have missed earlier. And it works. Thanks.